# In TinyMCE 4, editor.onBeforeSetContent.add() is deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I'm getting the following error in the console since I've upgraded from TinyMCE 3 to TinyMCE 4:

> Deprecated TinyMCE API call: .onBeforeSetContent.add(..)

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use

```
editor.on('BeforeSetcontent', function(event){
  console.log(event)
});
```